# how not to skip it further

Tags: angular, typescript

```
checkUser(){
  if (this.msisdn !== this.registerService.checkUser(this.msisdn)) {
    this.sendSms(0);
    console.log("asdasd")
    return;
  } else {
    console.log("5665")
    // this.toastr.warning('Пожалуйста зарегайтесь', 'Не получилось!');
    this.sendSms(1);
  }
}  

sendSms(i: number){
  this.auth.sendSms({msisdn:this.msisdn}).subscribe(res => {
  if (i == 1) {
    amplitude.getInstance().logEvent("sms resent");
  }
  this.showSmsCode = true;
})
```

I don't know how long I've been thinking here, help. Here's the idea itself: A person enters his phone number (this.msisdn), then I compare it with our database number is it there, if such a phone number does not exist in my database, then I tell him (you are not in our database) and do not skip further, if there is one, then I'm skipping it further

Comment: when coding a function   just do one thing in one function .Let your checkUser() function returns boolean (whether or not user exists) and in another function if checkUser() === true  send sms else print error. You seem get confused by making everythin in one function.

Comment: And what exactly is the problem?  Couldn't quite grasp it from your question.